# Blender gpu rendering uses one thread

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have a  Nvidia GeForce GT 740M gpu with 384 cores with driver version 430 installed in ubuntu 18.04 but while rendering , blender spawns only on thread so rendering on gpu is much slower than CPU with 8 threads.
I've already tried this in blender 2.80.4 and 2.80.7 but the problem still persists.
Also changing the number of threads manually has no effect.
[image]
Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Are your System Preferences (Edit->Preferences->System) for the Cycles Render Devices set correctly?

Comment: Yes.I set it to cuda .And also in render menu in the side panel.Nvidia settings window shows that it uses 100% of the gpu but in the render window I can see that blender actually uses just one thread.

Comment: GPU rendering in Blender always just calculates one tile at a time. This is unrelated to GPU utilization.

Comment: Can this affect the parallelism in rendering machines with hundreds of GPUs?